# How to give a 100% discount in Stripe for one-time payments and to some, not all, users? And how to integrate a discount input box into Stripe popup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I process payments via Stripe on my website. To some users, I want to give a 100% discount to my products. And also I want to test the payment process myself in the **live mode**, with the live keys, right on my production server, and that means that a 100% discount will come in handy for me too.

Is this possible? How?

P.S.
It's not a subscription, but a one-time payment.

Comment: Stripe recently released coupons for one-time payments but they still don't allow discounting below the minimum charge amount... So still no luck with a 100% discount. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts

Comment: From Stripe Support: "I'd say that you cannot add a 100% off discount in Stripe Checkout. It doesn't allow purchase below the minimum charge amount for one-time payments. The minimum amount is available here: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts
using 100% off, you'll have charges below the minimum amount."

Comment: UPDATE as of August 2023 Stripe have released a way to do this. They call it "no-cost orders" and the docs can be found here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/no-cost-orders
It essentially allows you to create 100% discount coupons, which when applied remove the payment form from the Stripe checkout. 
Depending on which version of the Stripe API you're using, you'll either have this functionality enabled by default or you'll need to activate it in your Stripe settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe makes it easy to use coupons for subscriptions. Applying coupons to standalone charges is typically a bit more nuanced. For instance, in an online store, coupons might depend on the cart total, might affect just shipping, or might only apply to certain items. As such, a coupon system for standalone charges is best implemented in your app. Fortunately, implementing a basic coupon system is easy.

After the certain time, you can disable the coupon which is created for the discount.

[**Link1**](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/discounts)

[**Link2**](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/coupons-for-charges)

Very nicely explained from Stripe, you can follow their documentation carefully.

Hope to help

Comment: `For instance, in an online store, coupons might depend on the cart total, might affect just shipping, or might only apply to certain items. ` -- I don't care what it depends on in some stores. I want to give a **fixed-percent or fixed-price discount** to **some users** .

Comment: Handle it at you server end.  generate coupon code and Implement logic corresponding to coupons and charge final amount to user

Comment: will Stripe still charge me any fees if the amount is $0? I mean, for processing a payment in the live mode. something like $0.1

Comment: Ok, then the idea is if skip payment for some users, then you create a column for users table which is data type is `boolean` or something like this then manually adds data, then create a logical part if users have data then skip the payment. and after the expiration date, you reset the data.

Comment: updated my comment.

Comment: well, that'll work but I want to use Stripe with a 100% discount still

Comment: Stripe will charge a minimum amount of 0.5$ not less than that.
read this link https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-amount

Answer (score 2):

Stripe doesn't support discount for one-time payments, If you want to give 100% discount to some specific users then charge them 0.5$ at your end and handle this at you code level.

If you just need for your testing purpose then stripe testing is very robust I am using stripe from the last 3-4 years still no issues with any feature.

id you need offer discount to the user then you can follow [this](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/coupons-for-charges) guide from the stripe to implement coupon system. you have to handle all coupon logic at your server 
But i think you just need for testing purpose.

Comment: you can have a look at this discussion thread why stripe doesn't support coupons for one time payment.

https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Stripe-not-allow-for-coupon-discount-codes-to-be-used-for-one-time-payments

Answer (score 0):

The stripe docs give a php example, and it's even 100%.
https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/discounts

Comment: I've said **P.S. It's not a subscription, but a one-time payment.**

Comment: Right, but notice all the other comments are... "use a subscription".